# Polycube with distinct rectangular faces

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, recreational-mathematics, polyhedra, packing-problem

Consider a polycube where all faces are rectangles. In addition to a cuboid, there is the unfolding of a tesseract, the approximation of an octahedron by cubes, and the object below. The component cuboids each have two ends with the same rectangle, namely the repeated $1\times2$, $1\times3$, and $1\times5$ rectangles.

[image: rectangular polycube]

What polycubes exist where all faces are distinct rectangles? Here are the six orthographic views of one solution:

[image: polycube with distinct rectangles]

This solution has 30 rectangles, is bound by a size 16 cube, and has maximal rectangle edge 15. Can any of these numbers be reduced? Some raw data for the below solution is at 
[Thirty Distinct Rectangle Polyhedron](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/928487).

[image: thirty rectangles]

Comment: Isn't your first picture a polycube where all faces are distinct rectangles?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean that all face dimensions are distinct?  That is, for example, only one rectangle side is of length 1?

Comment: The first picture has two 1x2 rectangles.

Comment: Oh, so you're looking for a polycube where the "end faces" are different.  (I'm sorry, but I was confused by what you meant by "face.")